# Symfony - Why the entity fields from an association between two entities are not loaded?

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, associations

I have two entities, **Mandate** and **Profile**.

There is an association Many-To-Many between them. This association is set up like that:

Mandate

```
class Mandate
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="mandates", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="lawyers_mandates")
*/
private $profiles;
```

Profile

```
class Profile
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Mandate", mappedBy="profiles")
*/
private $mandates;
```

When saving/editing a **Mandate** through a form, the **profiles** are well saved to the database.

The problem is that when I want to load a **Mandate**, the **profiles** aren't loaded with the object, despite all other fields are correctly loaded.

[image]

[image]

Here is how I am loading the **Mandate**

```
$mandate = $em->getRepository('KrownDashboardBundle:Mandate')->findById($mandateId);
dump($mandate[0]);
dump($mandate[0]->getProfiles());
```

Why **profiles** are not loaded? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's called Doctrine lazy loading aka Proxy classes.

Doctrine entities in relations won't be loaded until you first call them

You need to iterate over Mandate collection, not just `dump()` it

if you want them to be loaded with one query you need to either include Mandate with leftJoin and additional `select('m')` or define associacion as `EAGER`

#### Querybuilder with leftJoin solution (my preference)

```
class ProfileRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllWithMandates()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p', 'm')
            ->leftJoin('p.mandates', 'm')
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

#### EAGER solution

```
**
 * @Entity
 */
class CmsGroup
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="CmsUser", mappedBy="groups", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    public $users;
}
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html